# Remove certain characters from a regex group

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that looks like this (key":["value","value","value"])

```
"emailDomains":["google.co.uk","google.com","google.com","google.com","google.co.uk"]
```

and I use the following regex to select from the string. (the regex is setup in a way where it wont select a string that looks like this "key":[{"key":"value","key":"value"}] )

```
(?<=:\[").*?(?="])
```

Resulting Selection:

```
google.co.uk","google.com","google.com","google.com","google.co.uk
```

I want to remove the " in that select string, and i was wondering if there was an easy way to do this using the replace command. Desired result...

```
"emailDomains":["google.co.uk, google.com, google.com, google.com, google.co.uk"]
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse JSON, I'd suggest a JSON parsing module.

Comment: This is true, however I still would like to know if there is a good way to do this kind of replacement. @AKHolland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `\G` based regex to start the match with `:["` and further captures the values appropriately and replaces matched text so that only comma is retained and doublequotes are removed.

```
(:\[")|(?!^)\G([^"]+)"(,)"
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LWUGg2/1)**

Comment: this seems to do what i want, however i tried to do this in Perl, and this doesn't seem to work? $msgPayload =~ s/(:\[")|(?!^)\G([^"]+)"(,)"/$1$2$3/g; unless i'm missing something I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If your string indeed has the form `"key":["v1", "v2", ... "vN"]`, you can split off the part that needs to be changed, replace `","` by a space in it, and re-assemble:

```
my @parts = split / (\["\s* | \s*\"]) /x, $string;    #"

$parts[2] =~ s/",\s*"/ /g;

my $processed = join '', @parts;
```

The regex pattern for the separator in `split` is captured since in that case the separators are also in the returned list, what is helpful here for putting the string back together. Then, we need to change the third element of the array.

In this approach, we have to change a specific element in the array so if your format varies, even a little, this may not (or still may) be suitable.

This should of course be processed as JSON, using a module.  If the format isn't sure, as indicated in a comment, it would be best to try to ensure that you have JSON. Picking bits and pieces like above (or below) is a road to madness once requirements slowly start evolving.

---

The same approach can be used in a regex, and this may in fact have an advantage to be able to scoop up and ignore everything preceding the `:` (with `split` that part may end up with multiple elements if the format isn't exactly as shown, what then affects everything)

```
$string =~ s{ :\["\s*\K (.*?) ( "\] ) }{ 
    my $e = $2; 
    my $n = $1 =~ s/",\s*"/ /gr; 
    $n.$e 
}ex;
```

Here `/e` modifier makes it so that the replacement side is evaluated as code, where we do the same as with the `split` above. Notes on regex

- Have to save away `$2` first, since it gets reset in the next regex
- The `/r` modifier<sup>†</sup>, which doesn't change its target but rather returns the changed string, is what allows us to use substitution operator on the read-only `$1`
- If nothing gets captured for `$2`, and perhaps for `$1`, that means that there was no match and the outcome is simply that `$string` doesn't change, *quietly*. So if this substitution should always work then you may want to add handling of such unexpected data
- Don't need a `$n` above, but can return `($1 =~ s/",\s*"/ /gr) . $e`

Or, using lookarounds as attempted

```
$string =~ s{ (?<=:\[") (.+?) (?="\]) }{ $1 =~ s/",\s*"/ /gr }egx;
```

what does reduce the amount of code, but may be trickier to work with later.

While this is a direct answer to the question I think it's least maintainable.

---

<sup>†</sup>  This useful modifier, for "non-destructive substitution," appeared in v5.14.  In earlier Perl versions we would copy the string and run regex on that, with an idiom

```
(my $n = $1) =~ s/",\s*"/ /g;
```

In the lookarounds-example we then need a little more

```
$string =~ s{...}{ (my $n = $1) =~ s/",\s*"/ /g; $n }gr
```

since `s/` operator returns the number of substitutions made while we need `$n` to be returned from that whole piece of code in `{}` (the replacement side), to be used as the replacement.

Comment: Yeah, this works in my current case, but i doubt it would for all the request. The main issue is that i cannot get any modules installed, and that leads to a bump in the road, i have a couple of billion rows of data that i'm parsing and this seems to be the last issue i am having with my data set.

Comment: @MuamerBektić If you have varying input format we'd need to know more about it to suggest the "best" approach (it's just hard).  I've added a regex which may have a specific advantage, depending on the input format.

Comment: I can't seem to get that latest addition working in my perl script it spits "Bareword found where operator expected" out at me. And a big part of the issue is that i don't know what all the forms could be either. The example i gave was just part of a much longer json string. Then there is another occurrence of this same issue for me with "{"businessLogicTypeList":["FILEFORMATID","CHECKSUMTYPES","WAREHOUSETYPEID","IMSPROXYTYPE","IMSLINKTYPE","FILEDELIVERYSTATUSID"]}"

Comment: @MuamerBektić  Added another way with regex (but which should have no advantages over the first regex, except that it is shorter and uses lookarounds which you attempted)

Comment: @MuamerBektić "_a big part of the issue is that i don't know what all the forms could be_" -- yes, that's the biggest problem indeed.  You'd need to get an idea of what kinds of variations there can be in data.  (One --painful -- way to do that is to process, see what didn't work, adjust ... repeat.)

Comment: thank you so much for all of the help, however I am still getting the "Bareword found where operator expected" issue with the new regex.

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected ... near "s/",\s*"/ /gr". Doesn't seem to like that? I'm using perl  v5.10.1 if that matters.

Comment: @MuamerBektić Huh ... in the regex used in the replacement part of the big regex?  Can you debug that -- tweak it until the error goes away?  For example, change `/",\s*"/` to just `/,/` etc (Did you copy-paste correctly? Is there some silly typo in my code?)

Comment: I tried both and the only thing i changed was $string to my variable name so I'm not sure. And I've been messing with it and still get the bareword issue.

Comment: @MuamerBektić I don't see what could trigger _bareword_, other than some typo.  Is this the line on which you get that: `my $n = $1 =~ s/",\s*"/ /gr; ` ?

Comment: Sorry i got pulled into something, but yes, it is that line that throws an issue. I am not changing anything in regards to that.

Comment: @MuamerBektić Ahhh!   The v5.10 didn't have `/r` modifier yet.  Alright.  Edited

Comment: Going to mess with it in the morning. Thank you again so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your text is *almost* proper JSON, so it's really easy to go the final inch and make it so, and then process that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say postderef/;
no warnings qw/experimental::postderef/;
use JSON::XS; # Install through your OS package manager or a CPAN client

my $str = q/"emailDomains":["google.co.uk","google.com","google.com","google.com","google.co.uk"]/;
my $json = JSON::XS->new();

my $obj = $json->decode("{$str}");
my $fixed = $json->ascii->encode({emailDomains =>
                                    join(', ', $obj->{'emailDomains'}->@*)});
$fixed =~ s/^\{|\}$//g;
say $fixed;
```

Comment: the issue is I'm not creating the json, so I don't know how close it is to being a proper json, it comes in say 300-500 different forms, and this is the only I currently still have an issue handling. I am trying to parse all of the data into key value pairs and insert them into a table.

Comment: @MuamerBektić Trying to process structured data formats like JSON or HTML with regular expressions is asking for pain and suffering and has all sorts of issues. This is why my answer uses a module that understands the format. It's just easier and more robust that way. Makes 'insert into a table' a lot easier too, because then you can just access the values directly instead of this wierd not-quite-JSON output. Got a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here from the sounds of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `" *, *"`

Replace with: `,`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fiOyKH/1)

Comment: I know I could do that, however, I want it to only replace if it is between ':[' and ']' and that's where I am stuck.